# GoogleMap crashes randomly while zooming - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, segmentation-fault

I am using GoogleMap (`com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap`) in a pretty standard way to draw a route between two points over a GoogleMapFragment. After a few minutes browsing and zooming over the map, the activity containing this fragment crashes. I can see on DDMS that heap allocation is around 80%, and my last execution caused the log excerpt shown below.

I tried to `clear()` the map and limit the manimum amount of zoom allowed, but this only caused the crash to take a few more minutes to happen. My target is KitKat (4.4.2). Please, any help?

```
09-13 15:31:49.387: I/System.out(27068): Thread-2472(HTTPLog):automaticallyReleaseConnectionToPool: connection=com.android.okhttp.Connection@44a220d0, connectionReleased=false
09-13 15:31:49.407: I/System.out(27068): Thread-2472(HTTPLog):stream released with streamCancelled = false, connectionReleased = false, connection = com.android.okhttp.Connection@44a220d0, for engine com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsEngine@4471afd8
09-13 15:31:49.407: I/System.out(27068): Thread-2472(HTTPLog):make Reusable com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$FixedLengthInputStream@446c0010
09-13 15:31:49.407: I/System.out(27068): Thread-2472(HTTPLog):recycle connection com.android.okhttp.Connection@44a220d0
09-13 15:31:49.527: D/dalvikvm(27068): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4213K, 17% free 48683K/58204K, paused 63ms, total 64ms
09-13 15:31:49.537: I/dalvikvm-heap(27068): Grow heap (frag case) to 54.320MB for 4194320-byte allocation
09-13 15:31:49.557: I/System.out(27068): Thread-2471(HTTPLog):stream released with streamCancelled = true, connectionReleased = true, connection = null, for engine com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsEngine@44597bd8
09-13 15:31:49.587: A/libc(27068): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 29994 (pool-4-thread-4)
```

Comment: You are hitting a bug in the native android libraries. Have you tried your app in more than one device (model)? You really can't work around a SIGSEGV from java. Google Maps are very complex libraries that tightly interact with the hardware using opengl, lots of native code... Try different devices to see if this is firmware dependent, gms version dependent, or rather android dependent, and in the 2 latter cases you can file a bug to the Google Android Development forums. Sadly there's not much you can do imho.

Comment: Hi Klemenko, unfortunately (or not) I reported this bug to my manager and I had to move on, and since then the subject was dropped. I am sorry I have nothing else to add on it.